# $f:\mathbb{C}\rightarrow\mathbb{C}$ is entire function such that $g(z)=f(1/z)$ has a pole at $z=0$, then is $f$ surjective?

Tags: complex-analysis

$f:\mathbb{C}\rightarrow\mathbb{C}$ is entire function such that $g(z)=f(1/z)$ has a pole at $z=0$, then is $f$  surjective?
I can prove that $f$ will be a polynomial. and hence  $f$ is surjective. am I right?

Comment: Yes, since your polynomial must have degree at least $1$.

Comment: I suppose I should start posting answer as actual answers, even if they are very short.

Comment: are you using the result that an entire function with pole of order $m$ at inifity must be apolynom of degree $m$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, since your polynomial must have degree at least 1, this follows from the fundamental theorem of algebra.

(The fact that $g$ is a polynomial is proabably easiest to see from the Taylor series expansion of $f$ which immediately gives you a Laurent series expansion for $g$, but this is probably what you did already.)

Comment: Sir, I can't see why being a degree $\ge1$ polynomial means it is surjective